# Is there a tessellation with no corners?

Tags: curves, plane-curves, smooth-functions, tessellations

Is it possible to have a tessellation of the plane with no corners?

Here's what I mean precisely: Is it possible to tile the plane with tiles, each of which is the region enclosed by a smooth simple closed curve? Also assume that only finitely many tiles in any bounded region.

I don't think so, because when two of these smooth simple closed curves separate from each other, they should leave some sort of cusp that can't be filled by a smooth simple closed curve, but I'm not sure how to make this rigorous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Idea:**

Let $T$ be a tile and let $C$ be the smooth simple closed curve that bounds it. Traversing $C$ we pass a finite number of other tiles $T_1,\ldots,T_n$, because any bounded region contains only finitely many tiles. Note that $n=1$ is impossible as then $T_1$ is not enclosed by a smooth simple curve. Then $n\geq2$, and so $T$, $T_1$ and $T_2$ meet at a point $p$. At this point $p$ at least one of the three boundaries is not smooth by handwaving.

As suggested in the comments by Thomas Browning: As the boundaries of the tiles are smooth simple closed curves, their tangent vectors are well-defined at every point. Then for every pair of tiles meeting at $p$, traversing their boundaries in clockwise direction yields tangent vectors pointing in opposite directions. Repeating this three times then shows that the tangent vectors at $p$ are opposite to themselves, a contradiction.

**Original answer:**

It depends on what you mean by a *tessellation*: If you consider a covering of the plane by concentric annuli a tessellation, then there's an example for you.

Comment: those aren't regions bounded by smooth simple closed curves

Comment: Why not? Each region is bounded by two smooth simple closed curves. Again, it depends on what you mean by tessellation precisely.

Comment: ok, what I meant was that each region is the region enclosed by one simple smooth closed curve. I'll edit the question to make this more clear (I want the tiles to be simply connected to avoid this sort of thing)

Comment: Maybe the argument can be completed by looking at the angle between the tangent vectors at this point? These tangent vectors exist by smoothness, and I think you might be able to show that each angle is 180 degrees?

Comment: @ThomasBrowning I've added a wordy expansion of your idea; I think introducing a lot of notation would only make the idea less clear. Though I concede that this exposition isn't as clear as it could be. It's late here, I might try to rephrase it tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

The interior angle at any point along a smooth curve is 180 deg.
Two curved boundaries meeting at that point have a net interior angle of 180 + 180 = 360 deg.
That is the exact angle around the point. Any third tile meeting it must have an interior angle of 0 deg at that point.
0 is not equal to 180.
Therefore the third tile does not have a smooth boundary.
QED.

I think that even in a hyperbolic space having a total angle in a point of say 540 deg, the interior angle at a point on a smooth curve will be half the total. (but I could be wrong?)